# How to Parse GSON data into ArrayList<E>

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, gson

I have done following,

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<GameModel>> list = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<GameModel>>>() {}.getType())
```

Its giving me this error message.

> Error creating evaluation class loader:
>   com.intellij.debugger.engine.evaluation.EvaluateException: Method
>   threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception.

Although response have data, I am able to parse data in `Java Objects` by doing following, but unable to pass it in `ArrayList`

```
 GameModel gamModel= gson.fromJson(response, GameModel.class);
```

Kindly guide me how to pass data in `ArrayList`